# Non-delivery reports and VBA script in Outlook 2010

Tags: regex, vba, email, outlook, outlook-2010

I have a Outlook 2010 VBA script that should scan the body of selected non-delivery reports in my inbox and generates a text report if they match certain regular expressions in the body. Recently the script stopped working and it seems like I can no longer access the .body of the selected objects (debug.print outputs a lot of question marks to the immediate window).

The script still works fine for regular (not NDR) emails in my inbox. I also noticed that the non-delivery reports all of a sudden seem to be in an HTML (or rich text) format. The only thing I have done recently is compact my email archive and turn off cached mode.

Thanks for the help!

Here is the relevant script excerpt:

```
Set Reg1 = New RegExp
With Reg1
    .Pattern = "some pattern"
    .Global = False
End With

Set Reg2 = New RegExp
With Reg3
    .Pattern = "yet another pattern"
    .Global = True
End With

With objFile
    .Write sMarker1
    .WriteBlankLines (1)
End With

For Each objItem In ActiveExplorer.Selection
    countEmail = countEmail + 1
    objItem.UnRead = False
    If Reg1.Test(objItem.Subject) Then
        If Reg2.Test(objItem.Body) Then
            Set M1 = Reg1.Execute(objItem.Body)
            For Each M In M1
                With objFile
                    .Write M.Value
                    .WriteBlankLines (1)
                End With
            Next
        End If
    End If
Next
```

Comment: So from the looks of it, the actual pattern is _not_ the problem?

Comment: The patterns don't matter and could be removed from the example. It's accessing the ReportItem.Body Property of the objItem.

Comment: Are you sure you have ReportItem and not a regular MailItem object? NDRs are generated by your local transport provider or the Exchange service. If you get an NDR from an external server, it might not be a ReportItem object. What is the value of the objItem.MessageClass property?

Comment: I'm not sure, but it has the [icon](http://www.howto-outlook.com/pictures/icon/icon-report-ndr.gif) for an NDR next to the message in the navigation pane.

Comment: I double checked that the messages were in fact NDR using this code:If     UCase(objItem.MessageClass) = "REPORT.IPM.NOTE.NDR" Then
            MsgBox objItem.Body, vbOKOnly + vbInformation, "got one"
End If

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've been dealing with a very similar issue myself and can offer some insight into my discoveries, which I hope might be helpful in your situation.

If .Body for NDR messages are showing up as questions marks or Chinese characters then that's because the NDR is actually made by Outlook 'on the fly' using 'Properties' and by using certain methods inaccessible to VBA.

You can use an add-in called Redemption to gain access to all the information that normal VBA doesn't permit, but you need to install and register it on every PC you need the code to work with (which is OK if only YOU need to use it) but for me this wasn't an option.

The easiest alternative to what you were trying to achieve is to save the body using .SaveAs first and then read the contents back. I've made some functions that might make it easier.

```
//usage example:
theBody = GetNDRBody(MailItem)

Function GetNDRBody(rItm As Object) As String
    Dim TheBody, TempFilePath As String
    If (LCase(rItm.MessageClass) = "report.ipm.note.ndr") Then
        TheBody = rItm.Body
        If Len(TheBody) > 0 Then
            If Chr(Asc(Left(TheBody, 1))) = "?" Then
                TempFilePath = AppDataDirectory & "\temp.txt"
                rItm.SaveAs TempFilePath, olTXT
                GetNDRBody = ReadFileContents(TempFilePath, True)
            End If
        End If
    End If
End Function

Function ReadFileContents(filePath As String, Optional DeleteWhenFinished As Boolean = False) As String
    Dim fso As Object: Set fso = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")
    If fso.FileExists(filePath) Then
        Dim FileStream As Object: Set FileStream = fso.OpenTextFile(filePath, 1)
        ReadFileContents = FileStream.ReadAll
        FileStream.Close
        If DeleteWhenFinished = True Then fso.DeleteFile (filePath)
    End If
End Function
Function AppDataDirectory() As String
    Dim fso As Object: Set fso = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")
    AppDataDirectory = fso.GetSpecialFolder(2)
    Set fso = Nothing
End Function
```

HOWEVER - I'm not sure what exact information your scanning NDRs for, but it may also be possible to find an alternative way using a Property. 
For example, here is a snippet I used to fetch the failed email list from an NDR:

(it only works if they are displayed as an email in the NDR immediately below the title 'Delivery has failed to these recipients or distribution lists:'. If it instead shows as a contact name then only the name will be in that 'property'. In my case, when they showed as a contact name then I would use the GetNDRBody function I made)

```
Dim objItem As Object

If (objItem.MessageClass = "REPORT.IPM.Note.NDR") Then
    Dim propertyAccessor As propertyAccessor
    Set propertyAccessor = objItem.propertyAccessor

    FailEmail = propertyAccessor.GetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x0E04001E")
```

Sometimes there is a list of emails separated by "; " so I split it into an array and did a 'for each'

I also managed to get the email list from 'Mail Delivery Failed' emails this way, then spliting them into an array by ", "   (this is just a snippet again)

```
If objItem.Subject = "Mail delivery failed: returning message to sender" Then
    Set propertyAccessor = objItem.propertyAccessor
    FailEmail = propertyAccessor.GetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/string/{00020386-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}/x-failed-recipients/0x0000001F")
    FailEmail = Replace(FailEmail, ", ", vbNewLine)
...
FailEmails = Split(FailEmail, vbNewLine)
For Each FailedEmail in FailEmails
```

You can also try the below code to see if what you're looking for comes up as a common property (and you can also try installing OutlookSpy and see if there is a different property not listed here):

```
Set propertyAccessor = objItem.propertyAccessor
GetPropertyAccessorInfo propertyAccessor



Sub GetPropertyAccessorInfo(propertyAccessor As propertyAccessor)
   On Error Resume Next
   MsgBox propertyAccessor.GetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x001A001E"), , "PR_MESSAGE_CLASS"
   MsgBox propertyAccessor.GetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x0037001E"), , "PR_SUBJECT"
   MsgBox propertyAccessor.GetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x00390040"), , "PR_CLIENT_SUBMIT_TIME"
   MsgBox propertyAccessor.BinaryToString(propertyAccessor.GetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x003B0102")), , "PR_SENT_REPRESENTING_SEARCH_KEY"
   MsgBox propertyAccessor.GetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x003D001E"), , "PR_SUBJECT_PREFIX PT_STRING8"
   MsgBox propertyAccessor.BinaryToString(propertyAccessor.GetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x003F0102")), , "PR_RECEIVED_BY_ENTRYID"
   MsgBox propertyAccessor.GetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x0040001E"), , "PR_RECEIVED_BY_NAME"
   MsgBox propertyAccessor.BinaryToString(propertyAccessor.GetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x00410102")), , "PR_SENT_REPRESENTING_ENTRYID"
   MsgBox propertyAccessor.GetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x0042001E"), , "PR_SENT_REPRESENTING_NAME"
   MsgBox propertyAccessor.BinaryToString(propertyAccessor.GetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x004F0102")), , "PR_REPLY_RECIPIENT_ENTRIES"
   MsgBox propertyAccessor.GetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x0050001E"), , "PR_REPLY_RECIPIENT_NAMES"

   MsgBox propertyAccessor.BinaryToString(propertyAccessor.GetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x00510102")), , "PR_RECEIVED_BY_SEARCH_KEY"
   MsgBox propertyAccessor.GetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x0064001E"), , "PR_SENT_REPRESENTING_ADDRTYPE"
   MsgBox propertyAccessor.GetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x0065001E"), , "PR_SENT_REPRESENTING_EMAIL_ADDRESS"
   MsgBox propertyAccessor.GetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x0070001E"), , "PR_CONVERSATION_TOPIC"
   MsgBox propertyAccessor.BinaryToString(propertyAccessor.GetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x00710102")), , "PR_CONVERSATION_INDEX"
   MsgBox propertyAccessor.GetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x0075001E"), , "PR_RECEIVED_BY_ADDRTYPE"
   MsgBox propertyAccessor.GetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x0076001E"), , "PR_RECEIVED_BY_EMAIL_ADDRESS"
   MsgBox propertyAccessor.GetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x007D001E"), , "PR_TRANSPORT_MESSAGE_HEADERS"
   MsgBox propertyAccessor.BinaryToString(propertyAccessor.GetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x0C190102")), , "PR_SENDER_ENTRYID"
   MsgBox propertyAccessor.GetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x0C1A001E"), , "PR_SENDER_NAME"

   MsgBox propertyAccessor.BinaryToString(propertyAccessor.GetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x0C1D0102")), , "PR_SENDER_SEARCH_KEY"
   MsgBox propertyAccessor.GetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x0C1E001E"), , "PR_SENDER_ADDRTYPE"
   MsgBox propertyAccessor.GetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x0C1F001E"), , "PR_SENDER_EMAIL_ADDRESS"
   MsgBox propertyAccessor.GetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x0E02001E"), , "PR_DISPLAY_BCC"
   MsgBox propertyAccessor.GetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x0E03001E"), , "PR_DISPLAY_CC"
   MsgBox propertyAccessor.GetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x0E04001E"), , "PR_DISPLAY_TO"
   MsgBox propertyAccessor.GetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x0E060040"), , "PR_MESSAGE_DELIVERY_TIME"
   MsgBox propertyAccessor.GetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x0E070003"), , "PR_MESSAGE_FLAGS"
   MsgBox propertyAccessor.GetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x0E080003"), , "PR_MESSAGE_SIZE"
   MsgBox propertyAccessor.BinaryToString(propertyAccessor.GetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x0E090102")), , "PR_PARENT_ENTRYID"

   MsgBox propertyAccessor.GetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x0E12000D"), , "PR_MESSAGE_RECIPIENTS"
   MsgBox propertyAccessor.GetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x0E13000D"), , "PR_MESSAGE_ATTACHMENTS"
   MsgBox propertyAccessor.GetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x0E1B000B"), , "PR_HASATTACH"
   MsgBox propertyAccessor.GetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x0E1D001E"), , "PR_NORMALIZED_SUBJECT"
   MsgBox propertyAccessor.GetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x0E1F000B"), , "PR_RTF_IN_SYNC"
   MsgBox propertyAccessor.GetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x0E28001E"), , "PR_PRIMARY_SEND_ACCT"
   MsgBox propertyAccessor.GetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x0E29001E"), , "PR_NEXT_SEND_ACCT"
   MsgBox propertyAccessor.GetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x0FF40003"), , "PR_ACCESS"
   MsgBox propertyAccessor.GetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x0FF70003"), , "PR_ACCESS_LEVEL"
   MsgBox propertyAccessor.BinaryToString(propertyAccessor.GetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x0FF80102")), , "PR_MAPPING_SIGNATURE"

   MsgBox propertyAccessor.BinaryToString(propertyAccessor.GetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x0FF90102")), , "PR_RECORD_KEY"
   MsgBox propertyAccessor.BinaryToString(propertyAccessor.GetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x0FFA0102")), , "PR_STORE_RECORD_KEY"
   MsgBox propertyAccessor.BinaryToString(propertyAccessor.GetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x0FFB0102")), , "PR_STORE_ENTRYID"
   MsgBox propertyAccessor.GetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x0FFE0003"), , "PR_OBJECT_TYPE"
   MsgBox propertyAccessor.BinaryToString(propertyAccessor.GetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x0FFF0102")), , "PR_ENTRYID"
   MsgBox propertyAccessor.GetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x1000001E"), , "PR_BODY"
   MsgBox propertyAccessor.BinaryToString(propertyAccessor.GetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x10090102")), , "PR_RTF_COMPRESSED"
   MsgBox propertyAccessor.BinaryToString(propertyAccessor.GetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x10130102")), , "PR_HTML"
   MsgBox propertyAccessor.GetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x1035001E"), , "PR_INTERNET_MESSAGE_ID"
   MsgBox propertyAccessor.GetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x1045001E"), , "PR_LIST_UNSUBSCRIBE"

   MsgBox propertyAccessor.GetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x1046001E"), , "N/A"
   MsgBox propertyAccessor.GetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x30070040"), , "PR_CREATION_TIME"
   MsgBox propertyAccessor.GetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x30080040"), , "PR_LAST_MODIFICATION_TIME"
   MsgBox propertyAccessor.BinaryToString(propertyAccessor.GetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x300B0102")), , "PR_SEARCH_KEY"
   MsgBox propertyAccessor.GetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x340D0003"), , "PR_STORE_SUPPORT_MASK"
   MsgBox propertyAccessor.GetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x340F0003"), , "N/A"
   MsgBox propertyAccessor.BinaryToString(propertyAccessor.GetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x34140102")), , "PR_MDB_PROVIDER"
   MsgBox propertyAccessor.GetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x3FDE0003"), , "PR_INTERNET_CPID"
   MsgBox propertyAccessor.GetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x80050003"), , "SideEffects"
   MsgBox propertyAccessor.GetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x802A001E"), , "InetAcctID"
   MsgBox propertyAccessor.GetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x804F001E"), , "InetAcctName"
   MsgBox propertyAccessor.BinaryToString(propertyAccessor.GetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x80660102")), , "RemoteEID"
   MsgBox propertyAccessor.GetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x80AD001E"), , "x-rcpt-to"
End Sub
```